# Justify Content property is not working in display:flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here below is my css and html code I try hard to make `justify-content: space-between;` but not working
the class `.container` is important I can't remove max-width, is there any solution to fix the problem I also use `flex:auto , flex:0 0 auto` to shrink or give adjustable space to the elements but nothing works for me

Any help is highly appreciated

```css
.mega-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 35px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mega-wrap .container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1145px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dual-wrapper,
.max-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="mega-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dual-wrapper">
      Example 1
    </div>
    <div class="max-wrapper">
      Example 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.dual-wrapper, .max-wrapper { width: 50%; }` causes the issue. `justify-content: space-between` actually applied. However as there is no space left as 2x 50% = 100%, you will not see it. Remove the width and you see it works as intended. **Closing to vote: not reproduciable or caused by typos**

Comment: is there any solution to make `.dual-wrapper, .max-wrapper` equally 50% width because when i used it in my project its width adjusted automatically according to elements size,

Comment: would require scripting or setting it in a definite width such as 40%.

Comment: please check properly also `justify:flex-start` these types all tags not working

Comment: read above. The issue is still caused that 2 elements with a width of 50% equal a width of 100%. as such there will be no space between them as they fill the entire container by default. `flex-start` would apply but you dont see any difference as the same issue still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid any confusion, I removed all your CSS code and tried to match with what you want.

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
    
.dual-wrapper, .max-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dual-wrapper">
    Example 1
  </div>
  <div class="max-wrapper">
    Example 2
  </div>
</div>
```